# Have two oddly sized elements be center and edges against imaginery container responsively

Tags: jquery, html, css

The gist is simple with 50% widths like the above version shown in codepen, works as intended responsively, content is inside the imaginary container shown at the top the grey box. The issue arises when using uneven percentages thus fixed max-width will only work on a fixed window width.

**Is there a calc formula of some sorts to make it work? etc**

https://codepen.io/rKaiser/pen/NmNrXp

```
.uneven {
  .right,
  .left {
    width:65.3%;
    .content {
      max-width:420px;
      margin-left:auto;
    }
  }
  .right {
    width:34.7%;
      .content {
       max-width:180px;
       margin-left:0;
       margin-right:auto;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your container has a size equal to `W` (`600px` in your example) then our full container is full screen so `100vw` so the margin on both sides is equal to `(100vw - W) / 2` so your can simply use that margin with the inner elements.

The small drawback is that `100vw` include also the width of scrollbar, so the calculation will be slightly off when having a scroll bar:

```css
body {
  background: #666;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100px;
  background: #888;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.full {
  display: flex;
  background: orange;
  height: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.left {
  width: 50%;
  background: #16CC4A;
}

.left .content {
  margin-left: calc((100vw - 600px)/2);
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.right .content {
  margin-right: calc((100vw - 600px)/2);
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: right;
}

.right {
  background: #D98813;
  width: 50%;
}

.uneven .left {
  width: 65.3%;
}

.uneven .right {
  width: 34.7%;
}

@media all and (max-width:600px) {
  .left .content,
  .right .content {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <div class="full even">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="content">
        Edge
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="content">
        Edge
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="full uneven">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="content">
        Edge
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="content">
        Edge
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```